# Script to remove hotkey for internet-shortcut in windows

Tags: windows, shortcut, hotkeys

Everytime I start my computer the login-scripts create a shortcut in the start menu which also defines a hotkey for it. Unfortunately this hotkey collides with one of the default eclipse hotkeys so every morning I manually remove the hotkey from the shortcut.

Deleting or manipulating the shortcut doesn't remove the hotkey as well.

So how can the hotkey be removed with a script?

To be precise the shortcut is a shortcut to an URL. The file has the suffix `.url`.

The structure of the file seems to be an basic windows info file:

```
[InternetShortCut]
URL=http://...
...
Hotkey=1620
...
```

I am using Windows XP.

Comment: Edit the shortcut, remove the hotkey, then **set the shortcut to read-only**. That way, when the logon script runs and tries to update the shortcut, it fails.

Comment: Good idea, but the login scripts still overwrite the shortcut and thus restore the hotkey.

Comment: How about overwriting the shortcut with one that has no hotkey?

Comment: Does nothing; I assume windows stores the hotkey somewhere else and any manipulation on the shortcut has no effect on it. Except of course changing the hotkey of the shortcut to 'none'.

Comment: The hotkey is stored somewhere inaccessible to outsiders. But if removing the hotkey from the shortcut works, then write a program that edits the shortcut to remove the hotkey. (In which case this becomes a programming question again.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe some tweaking on the msconfig's startup and services tab can do some help

Comment: The shortcut is not created by a service but by the login to the domain. I don't have the priviledges to modify that, so the only way I see is to delete shortcut and hotkey afterwards.